# Estimote multiple beacons

Tags: estimote

I see this question Estimote: detecting multiple beacons with ESTBeaconRegion and startRangingBeaconsInRegion?

and it seems people have figured this out but it crashes my app. Is there an example of the array created and in use. If anyone could provide this bit of code i am sure many people would appreciate it.

Comment: Please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340385/how-declare-estimote-array-for-many-beacons?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

This is Wojtek Boroiwcz, I'm a community evangelist at Estimote.

Please refer to this thread on our community portal: https://community.estimote.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200966066-How-detect-multiple-beacons-iOS?locale=en-us It's explained in detail and with code examples. Hope that helps.

Cheers.